# How to test WebView in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have web view inside my State Full widget in flutter, How I can test the WebView in Widget testing? How to load URL in Web View from test class?

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible with [Patrol](https://patrol.leancode.co)!

Answer (score 0):

There is a driver in flutter to test WebView called as Appium Driver. I haven't tested it myself but while searching for WebView testing, I found this driver.

You can more read about this driver [here](https://dev.to/netfirms/flutter-app-testing-with-appium-flutter-driver-33ko)

Answer (score -7):

you can use the `initialUrl:` parameter for testing, like:

```
WebView(
   initialUrl: urlOne
)
```

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you 

Comment: _"I have web view inside my State Full widget in flutter"_